# vuejs 3: Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I cannot get rid of the error.
Somebody a tip why that is?

*I use vuejs in version 3 with a router.*

> Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

[image]

`npm run serve`

> WARNING  Compiled with 2 warnings
> warning  in ./src/router.js "export 'createRouter' was not found in
> 'vue-router'  warning  in ./src/router.js "export 'createWebHistory'
> was not found in 'vue-router'

`router.js:`

```
import { createWebHistory, createRouter } from "vue-router";
import UserSettings from "@/views/UserSettings.vue";
import UserEmailsSubscriptions from "@/views/UserEmailsSubscriptions.vue";
import UserProfile from "@/views/UserProfile.vue";
import UserProfilePreview from "@/views/UserProfilePreview.vue";
import Home from "@/views/Home.vue";
import About from "@/views/About.vue";
import Notfound from "@/views/Notfound.vue";

const routes = [
  { path: "/:catchAll(.*)", name: "Notfound", component: Notfound },
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "Home",
    component: Home,
  },
  {
    path: "/about",
    name: "About",
    component: About,
  },
  {
    path: "/settings",
    // You could also have named views at tho top
    component: UserSettings,
    children: [
      {
        path: "emails",
        component: UserEmailsSubscriptions,
      },
      {
        path: "profile",
        components: {
          default: UserProfile,
          helper: UserProfilePreview,
        },
      },
    ],
  },
];

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes,
});

export default router;
```

`App.vue`

```
<template>
  <h1>Nested Named Views</h1>
  <router-view />
</template>

<script lang="ts">
export default {
  name: 'App'
};
</script>
```

`main.js`

```
"use strict";
exports.__esModule = true;

import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'

createApp(App).use(router).mount('#app')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use Vue Router 4 with Vue 3

```
npm install vue-router@4
```